# undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app works perfectly locally, but I have some issues after deploying to Heroku.
When I want to create a new car, I click on "New car" link, which leads to `/cars/new`. App crashes, Heroku logs:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/cars_controller.rb:20:in `new'
```

This line in cars_controller is simply

```
@car = Car.new
```

In my app I use Devise, OmniAuth and nested resources, though car is a 'parent' resource, so it isn't a problem with nested routes or something. It works perfectly locally.

**UPDATE**: after seeding database with some cars, error dissapeared and it's possible to access cars/new. But when database is empty, it throws this error. What should I do?

Comment: Did you override the `initialize` method in the `Car` model? show us the Car class if you can.

Comment: No, my Car class is practically empty - just has_many :bookings

Comment: Please show us at least more stack for that error, this is an uncommon problem and we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something attribute name is a word reserved.